# adding nodes to tree force layout - almost working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with force layout and tree hierarchy.

It almost works and its adding nodes and links, but they are not visible.
Probably I am missing something trivial, but I have spent too many hours on this...
Any help greatly appreciated.

In this mock-up, after click, third node should be add to root.

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
   .linkDistance(80)
    .charge(-320)
    .gravity(0.05)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("#myviz").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

var mydata = '{ "name": "start_bubble", "children": [  {   "name":     "child_O1", "size": 31812},{   "name": "child_O2", "size": 31812}]}';
var myadd = '{"name": "new_child", "size": 100}';

root = JSON.parse( mydata); 
myaddparsed = JSON.parse( myadd); 

update();
force.start();

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")

    .style("stroke-width",2)
    .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 5 || 14.5; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "2.3em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
  force.start();
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
      : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
      : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
    }

// Toggle children on click.
 function click(d) {
  if  (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
    //    d._children = d.children; remove for testing
    //    d.children = null; removed for testing

root.children[2]=myaddparsed; //add third node

  } else {
    //    d.children = d._children; removed for tesing
    //    d._children = null;  removed for testing

root.children[2]=myaddparsed; //add third node

  }
  update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
   return nodes;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jo636df/o81xxmjm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You come to stackoverflow, and you say: "I index my data with the value of `i` incremented in `recurse`." But you don't maintain the value between calls to `flatten`. You don't offer uniqueness. You don't even think to tell D3 that you have new data. Instead, you reset `i` to 0, immediately increment it by one with `++i`, set it on your new element and you ask D3 to figure out that your new element is indeed new when you already have another element with `id` equal to 1.

You need to ensure your `id`s are indeed unique. As a quick fix you can pull `i` to the outer context to avoid resetting it to zero. Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc7hupq3/)**.